# How to swap the values of two variable without using third variable

Tags: php

How to swap the values of two variable without using third variable. I tried doing it with array but it doesn't work. Does anyone have a quick solution

Comment: use this logic-> `$a=$a+$b;
$b=$a-$b;
$a=$a-$b;` where `$a` and `$b` will have any value.

Comment: Post what you tried with the data you have. This is guesswork.

Comment: `[$a, $b] = [$b, $a];` ?

Comment: Even if you use list() like following:  *list ($a, $b) = [$b, $a];* it creates an array.

Comment: @Banzay It creates an array but discards it immediately. This is the same as what I suggested above (just with PHP<7 syntax). This looks like what OP is asking, but since it lacks details I can't be sure.

Comment: The answer depends on the nature of the data.  There are different techniques available if one can use bitwise techniques (for example). As others have noted, you can improve your post by supplying examples.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try like this**

> This will work for any variable type

```
$a = 10;
$b = 15;
list($a, $b) = array($b, $a);
print $a . ',' . $b;
```

> This below method will work only for numbers not for strings

```
$a =  $a + $b;  // 10 + 15 = 25
$b = $a - $b;   // 25 - 15 = 10
$a = $a - $b;  // 25 - 10 = 15
print $a . ',' . $b;
```

Comment: Just a note that `[$a, $b] = [$b, $a];` is the PHP 7.1+ equivalent of your first sample (and is therefore preferred for people using that).